# Ubuntu Studio 22.04: Increase Hyper-V resolution for guest OS

Tags: display, virtualization, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS inside a Hyper-V guest virtual machine, under Windows 11. When I connect to the VM using the "Virtual Machine Connection" (VMRC) client, the display resolution is limited to 1920x1080. However, I would like to increase the resolution to something like 4k (3840x2160) or at the very least, 3440x1440 (1440p).

**Question**: How can I configure the Hyper-V VM, or Ubuntu Studio guest OS, to "see" resolutions greater than 1920x1080?

I've included a screenshot of the available resolutions in the guest OS.

[image]

Comment: I have also been looking for a solution which doesn't need to install `xrdp` for a long time. however if you are not averse to `xrdp` and `xorg`, you can try [this](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-with-enhanced-session/). and you need to download the [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hinara/linux-vm-tools/ubuntu20-04/ubuntu/22.04/install.sh) for ubuntu 22.04 instead of that in the page.

Comment: @WoodsChen OMG that worked! Thank you! But for some reason, my Start keyboard button does not work in the RDP session. Have you seen that happen before?

Comment: That seems to be a configure in Windows 11. Before connecting to the RDP, switch to "local resource" tab, and select "on remote machine" option for "apply windows key combination".